# CSS layout with scrolling flexible panel

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a simple CSS-only layout and having a lot of trouble:

I want 3 vertical panels. The top panel -- '**banner**' -- stays fixed to the top of the outer container. Its height should be dictated by its contents -- I *don't want a specific or percentage-based height*. If I increase the font size, or insert a larger picture, the banner's height should change accordingly and the panels below should also change height accordingly.

The middle panel -- '**optional**' -- will contain some content that could also grow or shrink (so again, *no specific or percentage height*), and at times I may hide or remove the middle panel. Changes to the middle panel should affect the height of the bottom panel, but not the banner.

The bottom panel -- '**flexible**' -- should be anchored at the bottom of the container and grow upward. If it has more content can be displayed at its current height, it should display vertical scrollbars. ONLY this panel should display scrollbars -- I don't want them on the other panels or on the outer container. If the 'optional' panel shrinks or is hidden, the top of the 'flexible' panel should move upward, stopping only if there's no more internal content to display.

Here's my sketch. When the Optional element is displayed, the Flexible element should get a vertical scrollbar:

```js
$( function() {
  $('a').click( function() {
    $('.optional').toggle();
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
div, h1, p { margin: 0; padding: 5px; position: relative; }
h1 a { 
  font: .5em sans-serif; 
}

.container {
  outline: 1px solid pink;
  height: 420px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.banner {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}
.optional {
  outline: 1px solid orange;
}
.flexible {
  outline: 1px solid lime;
  min-height: 25%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row banner">
    <h1>Hello world <a href="#">toggle optional</a></h1>
  </div>  
  <div class="row optional">
    <p>Optional 1</p>
    <p>Optional 2</p>
    <p>Optional 3</p>
    <p>Optional 4</p>
    <p>Optional 5</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row flexible">
    <p>flex01</p>
    <p>flex02</p>
    <p>flex03</p>
    <p>flex04</p>
    <p>flex05</p>
    <p>flex06</p>
    <p>flex07</p>
    <p>flex08</p>
    <p>flex09</p>
    <p>flex10</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm having a very hard time getting this to work using only CSS. I've been using relative and absolute positioning in various combos, but they want to know the heights of the elements, and the heights are dynamic. I played with flexbox for a bit but couldn't get vertical expansion to work.

I could use all sorts of JavaScript -- when the document loads or the window size changes, get the outer container's height, get the computed height of the banner and optional panels, and set the height of the flexible panel to containerHeight - ( bannerHeight + optionalHeight ). But I'd like to avoid the JS if possible. Modern browsers only -- IE10+, Chrome/Safari/FF current, iOS, Android.

Possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you are okay using the flex properties, you may achieve this (young browsers only).
For older browser you will still need javascript to set live both heights to `.optionnal` & `.flexible` unless you allow `.container` to grow.

```js
$(function() {
  $('a').click(function() {
    $('.optional').toggle();
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
div,
h1,
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
}
h1 a {
  font: .5em sans-serif;
}
.container {
  outline: 1px solid pink;
  height: 420px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.banner {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}
.optional {
  outline: 1px solid orange;
  flex: 1;
}
.flexible {
  outline: 1px solid lime;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row banner">
    <h1>Hello world <a href="#">toggle optional</a></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="row optional">
    <p>Optional 1</p>
    <p>Optional 2</p>
    <p>Optional 3</p>
    <p>Optional 4</p>
    <p>Optional 5</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row flexible">
    <p>flex01</p>
    <p>flex02</p>
    <p>flex03</p>
    <p>flex04</p>
    <p>flex05</p>
    <p>flex06</p>
    <p>flex07</p>
    <p>flex08</p>
    <p>flex09</p>
    <p>flex10</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

[codepen to play with](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vOoZmW) (test with more content into optionnal )

Comment: Yes, I'm fine with flexbox, and this is VERY CLOSE! One problem: how would I make the Optional panel always display its entire contents -- no scrollbars, no hidden content? The Flexible bottom panel works correctly.

Comment: @Val - at one point, .optionnal could be taller than container. -In your question i see that you set min-height:25%;  - a phone, a tablet, a notepad is just enough to have a short or a too long .optionnal to be shown. Can you clear what you really try to do ? i'm confused now :) .

Comment: Banner is a set height based on content. It might change dynamically, but it's OK if it stays it's original height. Optional is dynamic in height & visibility - it holds search filters; depending on what you're searching for I may show more or fewer controls. It should always show its entire content, but the user can hide it after getting results. Flexible is the results - show as much as I can if Optional is shown, & show more if Optional is collapsed. 25%min-h was on Flexible to always show something, but is just a leftover experiment. Just need Optional to expand dynamically, no scrolling.

Comment: Good point on Optional being taller than container -- I could wrap both Optional and Flexible in a container and scroll that -- or just work to keep Optional entirely visible. Either way, I don't want scrolling on Optional, only on Flexible.

Comment: @Val so i guess the snippet up here should be it :) (not the codepen).

Comment: @CG, no, the inline version doesn't render properly at all. The Optional div is set to a fixed height, and its contents overflow its container. The Flexible div shows all 10 items & never shows scollbars. The CodePen works better - I'm just trying to get past setting the flex property on Optional to not have to be set to '1'. That tells the browser to size it proportionally to the other flex boxes, rather than to size it according to its contents. (Thanks, BTW, for playing w/this -- I'd understand if you have no more time or patience; this turns out to be MUCH harder than I expected!)